# How to set result as array in BFTask of Bolts iOS framework?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, bolts-framework

I've a method where I want to return array of structs on success of a Alamofire callback.

```
func getPopularMedias() -> BFTask {
  let instaUrl: String = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular"
  let user: PFUser = currentUser()
  let accessToken = user.objectForKey("accessToken") as! String
  var medias: [Media] = []

  let task = BFTaskCompletionSource()

  Alamofire.request(.GET, instaUrl, parameters: ["access_token": accessToken])
    .responseJSON { request, response, data in
      var json = JSON(data.value!)

      for(_, subJson): (String, JSON) in json["data"] {
        let image: UIImage = NSURL(string: subJson["images"]["low_resolution"]["url"].stringValue)
        .flatMap { NSData(contentsOfURL: $0) }
        .flatMap { UIImage(data: $0) }!

      let profileImage: UIImage = NSURL(string: subJson["user"]["profile_picture"].stringValue)
        .flatMap { NSData(contentsOfURL: $0) }
        .flatMap { UIImage(data: $0) }!

      medias.append(Media(name: subJson["user"]["full_name"].stringValue, image: image, profileImage: profileImage))
    }
    task.setResult(medias)
}
return task.task
}
```

While setting `task.setResult` I'm getting an error called `cannot convert value of [Media] to expected argument AnyObject!`

Currently I'm running this on XCode 7.0 GM release and swift 2.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `task.setResult` takes `AnyObject!`, which requires classes, or an array of classes. Structs do not fall into this category (It would actually work with `Any` designator). You can either convert your `Media` struct to a class, or encapsulate it in a class.

Answer (score 0):

Here`s one thing I would suggest you to do in that particular case. I see that you seem to be using SwiftyJSON, so what you could do is that you could pass json.rawData() as a result of a task and process it afterwards. Here is a real-life example.
I get some stuff from my database, get another set of data that is based on the initially acquired data and send it back to main function as json.rawData(). Afterwards, I am able to process my new data once I convert my NSData back to JSON.

p.s. You could also utilize a completionHandler, that will allow you to return whatever you want.

```
func startLoadingItunesDataFor(postsQuery: PFQuery, completionHandler: ((posts: [Post]) -> Void)) {
  var newPosts = [Post]()
  postsQuery.findObjectsInBackground().continueWithSuccessBlock({ (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    var tasks = [BFTask]()
    if let result = task.result {
      let posts = result as! [PFObject]
      for post in posts {
        let tempPost = Post(
          //////
        )
        newPosts.append(tempPost)
        tasks.append(self.getMovieInfoByITunesID(post["trackID"] as! Int))
      }
    }
    return BFTask(forCompletionOfAllTasksWithResults: tasks)
  }).continueWithSuccessBlock({ (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    let results = task.result as! NSArray
    for (index, postData) in results.enumerate() {
      let json = JSON(data: postData as! NSData)
       ////
    }
    completionHandler(posts: newPosts)
    return nil
  })

}



func getMovieInfoByITunesID(iTunesID: Int) -> BFTask {
  let mainTask = BFTaskCompletionSource()
  ITunesApi.lookup(iTunesID).request({ (responseString: String?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if
      //        error == nil,
      let responseString = responseString, let dataFromString = responseString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)

        do {
          try mainTask.setResult(json["results"][0].rawData())
        }
        catch {
        }
    } else {
      // process error
    }
  })
  return mainTask.task
}
```